# Unable to go back to Windows 8.1 after installing Ubuntu for dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-8

I own a Lenovo G500s touch laptop that originally came with Windows 8.1
I followed an online tutorial on how to dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu.
As of now, Ubuntu 14.04 loads up just fine after viewing a GRUB page at launch.
However, if I try to select Windows to launch in GRUB, I get an error telling me I cannot do so.
Here is the Ubuntu pastebin link that boot-repair generated: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10720355/
I am unsure as to which drivers are which. I have no experience with Ubuntu. I would greatly appreciate guidance in resolving this issue (a high-level description since I am not familiar with OS setting and things of the like). 
Other posts with similar issues seem to have their own individualistic approach to resolving the problem, so I posted here with my own pastebin link for specific assistance. 
Thank you!
P.S. this computer is near brand new. Thus, if I need to perform a factory reset (if applicable) I will.  I just need to know how to while I'm stuck in Ubuntu.

Comment: You installed Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM boot mode, but have Windows in UEFI boot mode. The two modes are not compatible, but you can dual boot from UEFI menu. You may have to turn on/off UEFI or CSM settings to match install. Boot-Repair can convert an Ubuntu CSM install to UEFI if you boot it in UEFI mode. Better to have installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode. Some advantages to UEFI over BIOS, but it is more complex as it offers more features. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Comment: Do not reinstall Ubuntu with any auto install options. That will erase entire drive including recover partition. Only use Something Else and choose same / (root) partition. And best to have full backups of Windows and a Windows recovery partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Ubuntu first, then you will need to do some manual steps to restore grub and boot windows. It sounds like with your system, the partition tables are messed up for the Windows installation.

This is the official documentation on dual boot:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

I would start by doing your factory wipe. I mean everything. Wipe the drive.

Install Windows to your liking in LEGACY mode so you don't use UEFI.

Then install Ubuntu how you normally would and keep Windows in the boot loader when prompted.

If you want to dive deeper with the install you already have, see the above link and note the section labeled "Recovering GRUB after reinstalling Windows"

This will provide more information:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2

It's technical and you'll likely need to boot from the live CD/USB and do your operations in a X GUI (it's a little easier).